# Dynamically load HTML from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some trouble with creating my popup directive in which I would like to get some template from server and place it in popup div then show it on screen. Also I would like this popups to have own controllers. Unfortunately it does not want to work. Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4U6wz/2/

I tried to put directive html inside of controller html like:

```
<div ng-controller="HeadCtrl">
    <a href="" popup="login.html">Login</a>
</div>
```

but it does not change anything. I get an error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: popupProvider <- popup 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=popupProvider%20%3C-%20popup 
minErr/<@http://fabrykakartek.dev/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78 
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://fabrykakartek.dev/bower_components
/angular/angular.js:3468 getService@http://fabrykakartek.dev/bower_components/angular
/angular.js:3595
```

Honestly I am rather AngularJS beginner so maybe I don't know about something. So hopefully someone can explain me if it can be done.
Greetings

EDIT: When I remove ng-controller from template it actually shows popup. So the question is why does ng-controller break this code ? It looks like there is something wrong with creating scope for this controller. Any ideas ?

Comment: sounds like you tried to inject the name of your directive into a controller. `xxxxProvider` type errors usually only show up when it is dependency injection issue

Comment: Your jsfiddle code _does not_ match the code you have posted in the question.  In the jsfiddle, where is `AuthCtrl` defined.  And where are you setting up `fabrykaApp` as your `ng-app`?

Comment: I actually dealt with this problem. Like charliefl said it was all because I tried to inject popup directive into controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('fabrykaApp', []);
```

try to add [] as second parameter